# Extract data from a corrupted .VMDK file

Tags: virtualbox, android, 7-zip, vmdk

I have a .vmdk file i exported from the Noxapp (android emulator), i tried to extract files with 7zip , there are 3 .img files. I can extract the 0.img and 1.img , but it gives me error "unexpected end of data" on the 2.img file which contain my data , is there any way i can recover my data?

Ps: even if i import the vmdk file to Noxapp android emulator, it stuck at loading screen and gives me an error which mean the file may be corrupted ...

Comment: vmdk is a vmware disk image format. Something you mount as a disk in a vm, or (assuming you got vmware workstatiom or similar installed) as in the same way you loopback mount an iso. It is not a compressed archive. Why are youtrying to open it with 7zip?

Comment: Yes i know but 7zip since version 15.09 beta can extract .ext2 and multivolume .VMDK images , this is why im using 7zip to extract files inside the vmdk file.

Comment: Cool. This is new for me. Might want to mention it in the post for others who also do not realise it.

Comment: From the number scheme, it seems like you've to join three files. Windows command: `copy /b *.img new.img`. Linux command: `cat *.img > new.img`. Then use 7zip to extract.